# Unrecognized symbols in Google Play store description

Tags: android

Sorry, this isn't a programming question, but I don't know where else to ask this.  I've noticed these symbols showing up in the "About this app" section of the Google Play listing.  When I go into the Play Console to edit, I'm just hitting "Enter" to go to the next line.  Yet, this symbol shows up at the end of the line.  Any idea on what is causing it and how to fix it?

These symbols only show in the Google Play Android app and **not** on the web site.

[image]

Comment: Your Mobile phone do not support these symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a side effect from a copy and paste.  If you have this issue, copy and paste the whole text into an editor like Sublime and you'll see all of the extra characters in the text.